# Adding Data to a Map in Firebase SetData - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Flutter and Firebase

I want to add data organised in a map to the document "18 - 08 - 2020" when the title of the map is different than an existing one.

[image: ScreenShot of my DataBase]

I don't know how to do it .. Here is my code :

```
  await db.collection('Suivi').document('${selectedDate.year} - ${selectedDate
             .month} - ${selectedDate.day} ').setData({'$Userr' :{'Num': '$Num ',
           'time': time,'Dur': Dur,'Num1' :Num1,'Num2': '$Num2 ','Remarks': '$remark ' }});
```

The method setData update the content of the map even if the title of the map ('$Userr') is different than an existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Umm, the title of the map ($'User') doesn't matter. setData() will only update the document whose id you have provided (it can also create a document if it doesn't exists).

However, if you don't want to overwrite the previous data, you can set `merge=true`, so that, only the field value which is changed, gets updated, not the whole map.